# gcc include path and symlinks

Tags: gcc, include, symlink

I am trying to compile Macports on Snow Leopard—specifically, the file `src/macports1.0/get_systemconfiguration_proxies.c`.  This `#include`s `CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h`, which `#include`s `CoreFoundation/CFBase.h`, which … *tries* to `#include` `CoreServices/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h`.  Now, `CoreServices` is a symlink:

```
$ ls -l CoreServices
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  62 Mar 25 17:15 CoreServices -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers
```

so I suspect that the goal is to get to `../../System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h`, which is a perfectly fine thing to do:

```
$ ls -l ../../System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  30291 Jun 24  2010 ../../System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h
```

However, `gcc` doesn't like it:

```
In file included from $INCLUDE/CoreFoundation/CFBase.h:48,
                 from $INCLUDE/CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h:38,
                 from get_systemconfiguration_proxies.c:42:
$INCLUDE/CoreServices/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h:20:42: error: CarbonCore/ConditionalMacros.h: No such file or directory
```

which leads me to suspect

(**EDIT**:  But [Tom Zych](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440300/gcc-include-path-and-symlinks/5440502#5440502) points out that I suspect wrongly, because I didn't finish reading the error message.  *Sigh*.)

that `gcc` may not be resolving the symlink, and instead over-smartly collapsing `CoreServices/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h` to `Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h`, which, sure enough, doesn't exist:

```
$ ls -l Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h
ls: Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible that I have interpreted the error correctly?  If so, is there any way to talk `gcc` into following the symlink before `cd`'ing to `..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message ends with:

```
$INCLUDE/CoreServices/../Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MacTypes.h:20:42: \
error: CarbonCore/ConditionalMacros.h: No such file or directory
```

It appears that it was able to read and start processing `MacTypes.h`, since it's referring to line numbers therein. The file it can't find is `CarbonCore/ConditionalMacros.h`.

I would guess `CarbonCore` should be `CarbonCore.framework`. Why this hasn't long since come up and been fixed, I don't know. Perhaps it's a recent change.

Comment: Wow, I've been staring at that for a full day, and it just turns out that I can't read error messages to the end of the line.  Thanks!